# Hiding youtube videos when hidden with jquery

Tags: jquery, youtube

There are a couple of similar questions here already but none seem to work for my application.

On my website I'm opening up a lightbox with embedded videos for a user to watch. They click a thumbnail and the video appears to the right of the thumbnails. Here's the javascript code I'm using:

$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.vidframe').hide();

```
    $('a').click(function () {

        $('.vidframe').hide();
        $('#'+this.id.substr(4)).fadeToggle(400);
    });



});
```

And jsFiddle link to semi-working example: http://jsfiddle.net/YX8pQ/24/

However, when changing from one video to the next, the video won't stop. I tried removing it from the DOM by changing

```
$('.vidframe').hide();
```

to

```
$('.vidframe').remove();
```

However this, uh, removes all the videos from my DOM and ruins things completely. Is there a way to hide the videos when clicking from one to another, but stop playback AND buffering of the iframe? I feel like I'm on the right track with .remove() but don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi i just glimpsed at your code.

You have everything ok but the reason the movie does not stop is just because hide. is setting visible:none;  So they are still going to be playing.

The way to do it is to create dynamic iframes with some ID on it.

When somebody clicks on the next movie it will .remove() the current movie. put the new one in its place with an ID you remember somewhere. And then reinstert the removed one in a hidden iframe so it can prebuffer and get ready invisibly. You should not actually do hidden loading but if you not going to have allot of movies its fine- its only problematic when you start pre loading tens of movies.

EDIT

Ok so i basically ripped your code apart and mode some structure to it- also i use about 30% less code- because i make jquery do the hard work.

This does not preloaded your movies though as that is a very bad practice and can cause your site to load "slowly" if you start adding masses of movies. This literally replaced the clicked one ,fades in an d you can play it.

Check the new version of your fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/YX8pQ/25/

and also read these- maybe you will be able to make something better.

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/iframe_api_reference.html

[Stop all YouTube iframe embeds from playing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503833/stop-all-youtube-iframe-embeds-from-playing)

Comment: Great, thanks for the advice. However, I'm a bit new when it comes to javascript/iframes, can you elaborate on how to create them dynamically and what kind of javascript I'd have to use? Appreciate your help.

Comment: OK- i fiddled your code- you have a good example of how to fully use jQuery and how to structure your code. look at the way i remade your CSS - that is the proper way to use it and i removed allot of unnecessary divs,a tags and other stuff. jQuery understands the cascading of CSS the same way- Look at my edit above

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH mate, this was by far the most helpful response I've ever had on here and I really am very grateful - your fiddle will help me learn to code better, as I'm pretty much a novice at the moment. Cheers.