# stopping a youtube video in a modal window when modal is closed

Tags: jquery, youtube-javascript-api

I am trying to do something really simple. I have a bootstrap modal window where I am putting a youtube iframe video like this:

```
<iframe id='youtube-player' width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/AYPePO0oa_o?rel=0&wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I'd like to use bootstrap's close class to just top the video. I have this but not working (obviously)

```
$('.close').on('click', function(){
  alert('here you are');
  $('#youtube-player').stopVideo();
});
```

This should seem like it should be really simple but I'm not sure what I should be doing? Any help would be appreciated.

thx in advance,

jonathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it has something to do with the way you embed the iframe to start with.

Have a look at this question its not exactly the same but it's similar: [Stop all YouTube iframe embeds from playing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503833/stop-all-youtube-iframe-embeds-from-playing)

And this is the You Tube developers reference from Google on how to embed iframes if you want to use the controls: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

That should have all the info you need.

Answer (score 3):

```
<body>
<div class="modal" id="modalId" >

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" >
$('#modalId').bind('hide', function () {
    var iframe = $(this).find('iframe');
var src = iframe.attr('src');
iframe.attr('src', '');
iframe.attr('src', src);
});
</script>
</body>
```